# tar -zxvf cannot unzip file

Tags: shell, ftp

here's the problem:

**First step**

transfer the *.gz file to the remote host using ftp, the code below

> open $IP
>
> user nfc nfc123
>
> bin
>
> passive
>
> cd /nfc/APPBAK
>
> put $FULLNAME $DESTFILE
>
> cd $DESTDIR
>
> tar -zxvf $local_filename
>
> quit
>
> FTPIT

**Second step**

> tar -zxvf $local_filename

*but it says:*

> "?Invalid command. "

Should I change the mode of of the *.gz file first, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run the `tar` command inside FTP, as far as I can see, rather than in the shell after you've fetched the file with FTP.  It is confusing since some shell commands, like `cd`, seem to work in FTP too, but the `cd` command actually attempts to change directory on the remote machine (you need `lcd` to change directory on the local machine).

Put simply, `tar` isn't a valid FTP command, which is why you get the `?Invalid command` error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually, you points out the key part of my problem.So I have to code another shell script which runs in the remote machine to unzip this .gz file, got your meaning?

Comment: Yes, you would need to run the `tar` command on the remote machine via something other than FTP.  It is the 'File Transfer Protocol'; maybe you need SSH instead, or as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this one::

```
tar -xvf $local_filename
```

Please make sure that file has right permissions.

Comment: whats content of the $local_filename? first create the tar file then try to ftp that tar file. You have to tar up the directory from a command prompt when you are logged into the server. Then you connect via FTP and copy the file.

Comment: Actually do the same as you descripted